# how to restrict schema using trigger on saturday and sunday

Tags: oracle

```
create or replace trigger login
after LOGON ON DATABASE

begin

    if to_char(sysdate,'dy')in ('sat','san') then
    raise_application_error(-20123,' we cant logon the database ');   
    end if;

end;
```

Comment: schema restricted on satarday and sunday

Comment: write more description to your question

Comment: on satarday sunday we con not logon the schema it will showing exception by using trigger

Comment: Well, Sunday is `sun`, not `san`. Apart from that, what is the problem?

Comment: sorry for my mistake ,i correct it but its not working

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Answer (score 0):

compile it with sys user..
sample trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER login_trg
AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
DECLARE

BEGIN
   IF to_char(SYSDATE,'D') NOT IN ('6','7') THEN
      raise_application_error(-20123,' we cant logon the database ');   
   END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is an English database? You can hard-code the language in your `TO_CHAR` without changing the system or session NLS parameters. This might be preferable to remembering whether Oracle weeks start at 1 or 0 or whether they start on Sunday or Monday in your particular locale.

(Today is Tuesday as I test this.)

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'ENGLISH';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dy') FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(SYSD
------------
tue

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'SPANISH';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dy') FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(SYSD
------------
mar

SQL> -- This will work even though our session is still in Spanish.
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''ENGLISH''') FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(SYSD
------------
tue

SQL>
```